# Python websockets - Loop y listener en el mismo websocket

Tags: python, websocket

Estoy intentando crear un websocket con Python que envíe datos al cliente mediante un bloque while (solo enviar), pero al mismo tiempo necesito que este websocket reciba mensajes del cliente y le envíe una respuesta según el mensaje recibido. Ambos envios (el while y el generado por el mensaje del cliente) deben ser independientes uno del otro y no deben interferir entre si. Puedo hacerlo con dos websockets separados, pero necesito vincularlos en uno solo.

Este es mi código del lado del servidor (lo más resumido posible):

```
import asyncio
import websockets

#CONFIGURACION DEL WEBSOCKET
async def EstructuraWS (WS):
    while True:
        await WS.send ('Mensaje enviado por loop')
        await asyncio.sleep (1)
    async for Mensajes in WS:
        await WS.send (f"Tu mensaje fue: { POST }")

async def ServirWS ():
    async with websockets.serve (EstructuraWS, '0.0.0.0', 4444): await asyncio.Future ()

asyncio.run (ServirWS ())
```

El cliente es el propio navegador (la API de Javascript). No creo necesario poner el código del cliente (si es necesario avisenme y edito la pregunta). El cliente basicamente se conecta por la API Websockets a **ws://127.0.0.1:4444**, tiene un **onmessage** que copia en un div lo que recibio del servidor, y un boton que envia un texto tecleado en un input.